# Python 3 on Atom using Script package on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor

I am trying to run Python3 on atom editor using script package (Windows). I have python 2.7 installed as well. I cannot change the settings to use python 3. Here are the things I have tried:

1. I changed the mycomputer->properties->advanced settings->environment variables->PYTHONPATH to python3 executable location 
   C:\Users\\Programs\Python\Python36
2. In atom, under File->config I changed the 
   pythonPaths:"C:\Users\\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe"
3. I also tried packages->Script->Configure Script and tried following options for Command

   C:\Users\\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe

   C:\Users\\Programs\Python\Python36

   C:\Users\\Programs\Python\Python36

   C:/Users//Programs/Python/Python36

but none of them seem to work.

To check the version, I am using

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

which outputs

2.7.11 (v2.7.11:6d1b6a68f775, Dec  5 2015, 20:40:30) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Answer (score 0):

Atom will use whichever version of python is the default for the directory you run it from. I run atom using the command line on a mac. If I run python from a directory and it open a python 2.7 line, running atom from same directory will result in atom using python 2.7. I know you don't have access to unix window on a Windows machine but same should apply.